# Error when running TLauncher

Tags: kubuntu, lubuntu, games, playonlinux, minecraft

i have this error while trying to start TLauncher-2.86.jar in Ubuntu 20.04.

[image]

Comment: look now to the post I added the information

Comment: It's still not clear as you mention Ubuntu 20.04 (Thank you), but also you're logged into two different desktops (LXQt for Lubuntu, and KDE Plasma for Kubuntu), but your paste looks more like `gnome-terminal` as it uses colors neither Lubuntu or Kubuntu use?  Please clarify your chosen tags as you can only login with a single DEsktop during a session.

Comment: The key is to provide specific details of your problem and the platform (OS version) in question that you are experiencing the problem with.

Comment: where can i get this details ?